# sorting the list with string inside

Tags: python

I need your help again, I'd like to sort a list.  The sorting is based on the number before A or B

How to do it? Thanks

```
original list:

['1A21','1B21','21A21','21B21','14A21','14B21'....]

the length of string with A and B are not the same. For example, there are '31A21', but there is no '31B21'

sorted list:
['1A21','2A21'........'1B21','2B21'.......]


My original code is for the case only has either A or B inside the string:

wells.sort(key=key_sortwell,reverse=True) 

def key_sortwell(well):
      return int(well.split('A')[0])

But now I have both A and B inside the string. Now I am not sure how to do it?
```

Comment: that is incorrect syntax, are the items strings?

Comment: Yes, sorry all the items are strings, thanks

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
You need to learn some string processing and how to supply a custom sort key.

Comment: I did. I will pose my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how you want to break ties -- if you want to sort first on the first number, then on the letter, then on the second number, etc, I might suggest using a `key` function that will split the string into numbers and letters:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> original_list = ['1A21','1B21','21A21','21B21','14A21','14B21']
>>> sorted(original_list, key=lambda s: [int("".join(group)) if d else "".join(group) for d, group in groupby(s, key=str.isdigit)])
['1A21', '1B21', '14A21', '14B21', '21A21', '21B21']
>>> sorted(original_list, key=lambda s: [int("".join(group)) if d else "".join(group) for d, group in groupby(s, key=str.isdigit)][1::-1])
['1A21', '14A21', '21A21', '1B21', '14B21', '21B21']
```

Breaking down that `key` expression with a single string makes it easier to see how it works:

```
>>> [(d, list(group)) for d, group in groupby("1A21", key=str.isdigit)]
[(True, ['1']), (False, ['A']), (True, ['2', '1'])]
>>> [(d, ''.join(group)) for d, group in groupby("1A21", key=str.isdigit)]
[(True, '1'), (False, 'A'), (True, '21')]
>>> [(d, ''.join(group)) for d, group in groupby("1A21", key=str.isdigit)][1::-1]
[(False, 'A'), (True, '1')]
>>> [int(''.join(group)) if d else ''.join(group) for d, group in groupby("1A21", key=str.isdigit)][1::-1]
['A', 1]
```

When you compare lists for sorting purposes, the first elements are sorted first, etc.

Comment: Thanks Samwise, i tried and the result are the same, it become ['1A21',1B21',2A21','2B21'....] what i wanted is ['1A21',2A21'.....'1B21',2B21'] Thanks

Comment: You said you wanted to sort based on the number at the start of the string.  Why do you have a 1 following a 2?  What happened to 14 and 21?

Comment: Thanks Sam, Sorry for not being clear. I appreciate your help. 21 after A or B doesn't need to be consider, firstly need to group the list into strings with A and B, then for each group, sort the list based on the number before A or B. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: `sorted(original_list, key=lambda s: [int("".join(group)) if d else "".join(group) for d, group in groupby(s, key=str.isdigit)][1::-1])`?

Comment: Yes, Samwise, that worked  perfectly. Thank you Sir! I really appreciate it. You made my day!

Comment: Sam, I am trying to understand your code, I don't understand how it works.  Would you mind explaining it a bit? Thanks

Comment: Added a bit to my answer that breaks down each step.  Most of the important stuff happens in `groupby`, which is what lets you break the string into numbers and not-numbers.

Comment: Got it now, You have an excellent coding skill. I can never do that way. Thank you Sam again! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the builtin `sorted` function with a key function that takes each string and returns the number before either `A` or `B`

```py
sorted_lst = sorted(original_lst, key=lambda s:s.replace('B', 'A').split('A')[0])
```

Comment: thanks Hadrian, unfortunately this doesn't work